# What is a listener's typical audible angular resolution?

Tags: acoustics, audio, psychoacoustics

According to wiki, the human **eye** has an angular resolution of ~1 arcminute, which means
you can distinguish things that are 30 centimetres apart at a distance of 1 kilometre.

But your **ears** have a **much** lower angular resolution than that. Any idea what it might be?

The thing that prompted this question was - when I looked at the balance control in an audio mixer, and it allows continuous control. I think if I change the balance by 10% I probably couldn't hear the difference. Does the balance pot really need such fine resolution?

After posting this, I realised that a balance fader changes the relative **levels** of a signal reaching each ear. But when you listen to a sound in a room your brain can locate the source of the sound because (amongst other things) the audio arrives at your ears at different **times**.

And so moving the balance fader from one extreme to the other produces an effect  that is only superficially similar to that of a performer walking from one side of the stage to the other.

Comment: It will depend on the mix. If some instrument is panned hard l or r, you will hear a 10% shift.

Comment: Human directional hearing is a bit more complicated than just different volume for each ear.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not really depending on music, but a addresses a general perceptional/physiological/psycho-acoustic question.

Comment: There's more than one question here (and not music but biologic).  We easily "sense" continuous motion of a sound source, but whether we can assign a static position to high accuracy is a separate question.

Comment: @Brian  perhaps to answer your question -  Listen to some engineered rock recordings such as the early EmersonLake&Palmer stuff.  You can easily sense the virtual source sliding smoothly from -90 to +90 degrees in azimuth.

Comment: Could you cite the exact page with the 1 arcminute claim? E.g. this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_localization#ITD_and_IID says _"Localization accuracy is 1 degree for sources in front of the listener and 15 degrees for sources to the sides."_ I think I recall seeing a paper reporting much better resolution, but perhaps it was possible with some very specific testing technique? One needs to be careful when generalizing. Moreover, simple panning doesn't affect phase differences (I think there are dedicated plugins that can pan with phase, perhaps those made for binaural recordings).

Comment: @guidot The question is about application of psycho-acoustic knowledge to music mixing. Maybe it would fit a bit better Sound Design SE, but I don't think it's really off-topic here, the division between MP&T and SD seems not to be very well defined so far.

Comment: Our ability to locate sound in free space is likely to be better than our ability to locate sound from a stereophonic representation. The ear has more cues to work with in "real life".

Comment: If you are mixing a track in a good listening environment then having the pan knob of a particular instrument off-centre by a small degree definitely gives a sensation that the sound is no longer full centred. Similarly, if a mix is a little unbalanced, ie overall louder left or right then it can sound really a bit awkward and amateurish, the movements you need to make on the pan knob to balance the left and right (should you choose to do it this way) can be very small but it still has a strong effect. Play a mix in a DAW and use the pan, you may realise you can detect more than you think.

Comment: @user1079505 Although my feelings are generally broad about what we leave open, I see this as "a biological question with *implications* for music." One of the reasons for closing and reposting elsewhere is not just "humph, we don't wanna talk about that," but the fact that another site might have better expertise. This one beats the heck out of me. I wonder if it's actually better under medicine...

Comment: @user1079505 the arcminute is for eyes, not ears.

Comment: @ojs Ah, I misread, thank you. 1° for the ears is quite impressive anyway!

Comment: It is. I was really surprised humans are so good, even dolphins can't do better.

Comment: I don't think the eye's resolution is really 1' in the sense of “you can distinguish things that are 30 centimetres apart at a distance of 1 kilometre”. That would be a valid interpretation for a digital camera whose pixels have an effective size of 1', but the human eye doesn't work like that – it has various optical abberations and no regular pixel grid, but all of this is to some degree accounted for by deconvolutions performed by the visual cortex. As a result, we can distinguish some features that are as small as 1', but certainly not _visually measure positions_ that accurately.

Comment: Now that the question has been edited, could you explain what would be gained by having discrete steps instead of a continuous balance pot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The human brain has several different ways to localize sound depending on the pitch and the direction of the sound. These include not only volume difference between ears, but also timing difference for higher frequencies and the way earlobes filter the sounds coming from different directions. Simulating all of these on a stereo recording requires that listener wears headphones and the recording is done using artificial head or HRTF filtering that simulates the listener's head. In optimal conditions, using all these cues, for sound sources in front of the listener, the resolution is about 1 degree. The minimum audible volume difference between ears is 0.5dB.

Sources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_localization, Thomas D. Rossing: The Science of Sound

For the "Does the balance pot really need such fine resolution?", continuous adjustment has the benefit that it is simple to implement. Adjustment from -90dB on one channel to -90dB on other at 0.5dB increments would require 360 discrete steps, which is not really simpler than continuous adjustment. Consider that high end consumer audio manufacturers can sometimes resort to really complicated solutions for very small or nonexisting sound quality improvements and even there discrete volume adjustment is uncommon.